# Getting values from data attribute not working

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to do what's explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691262/html5-loading-a-section-content-into-a-main-view-wrapper) where there is an useful jsfiddle link in the accepted answer.
I got a basic page like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        section {
            display: none;
        }

        #home { height: 200px; background: beige; display: block;}
        #products { height: 1000px; background: honeydew; }
        #contact { height: 500px; background: seashell; }
    </style>
    <title> Leggy </title>

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("a").on("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).data("section");
            alert(id);
            $("section:visible").fadeOut(function() {
                $(id).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" data-section="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#" data-section="#products">Products</a>
<a href="#" data-section="#contact">Contact</a>

<div id="wrapper"></div>

<section id="home">Home</section>
<section id="products">Products</section>
<section id="contact">Contact</section>

</body> 
</html>
```

But then when running it Firefox console says just that getUserData() and setUserData() are deprecated. I can't really understand what does that mean and how to fix it, since this is the only thing that could be an issue, for what I can see..

What actually happens is that script is not executed, I would say, since the alert is not launched.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: love people who downvote questions without explainations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all in [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").on("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).data("section");
            alert(id);
            $("section:visible").fadeOut(function() {
                $(id).fadeIn();
            });
        });
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huzbw/)

Comment: thanks dude. I know this was trivial but I'm totally new to jQuery. Great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript code is being executed before the necessary elements exist in the DOM - you can't attach the `click` event to the `a` element before the `a` element exists.

To remedy this you should put `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` around your Javascript, which will make sure the code will only be run once the page has loaded and the DOM is set up.