# How to get #hash value in a URL in JS

Tags: javascript, url

For example, I have a URL as :

> http://www.google.com/#hash=value2x

I want a js code to return just `value2x`.
I tried `location.hash.split('=')[1]` but that results the first hash value like if url is

> http://www.google.com/#hfh=fdg&hash=value2x

It returns `fdg&hash`.
I want just the value of `hash`.

NO jQuery Please.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
function getHashValue(key) {
  var matches = location.hash.match(new RegExp(key+'=([^&]*)'));
  return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}

// usage
var hash = getHashValue('hash');
```

Comment: This results everything after `hash=`

Comment: It should be noted that this will cause an error if there is no hash or if the key does not exist. [This is a more fail-safe version of the answer](http://jsfiddle.net/8gJCY/).

Comment: @xdazz: as Hectron said, a TypeError gets raised if there is no hash, so you should check the length of the array returned by `match` method and only index this array if its length is greater than or equal to 2. If not, you should return an empty string or null (or undefined).

Comment: It should also be noted that "key" will be interpreted by the RegEx parser, so having a legit key containing a dot or a single brace this will lead to results differing from expectation or even errors

Comment: Should correct like:
return matches && matches.length === 2 ? matches[1] : null;

Answer (score 17):

The URLSearchParams class can be reused for this purpose.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.replace("#","?"));
var hash = urlParams.get('hash');
```

Comment: Or you can also use `window.location.hash.slice(1)` instead.

Comment: That code is incorrect through. Rather than replacing "#" by "?" it should be removing the "#". So replace replace("#","?") by slice(1)

Comment: @Clox Well no, that would just merge the first key in the hash section with the last value in the parameter section, or merge it with the path. Either # needs to be replaced by ? (if there are no url parameters) or with & (if there are already parameters). But regardless this is a bad way to do it because youll pull url parameters as well.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
location.hash.split('hash=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

This will split the hash at `hash=` and take the value after hash= and before any other argument .

Comment: This as is does not work, making it `location.href.split('hash=')[1].split('&')[0]` works

Comment: Need to test more, Upvoting now

Answer (score 2):

```
location.parseHash = function(){
   var hash = (this.hash ||'').replace(/^#/,'').split('&'),
       parsed = {};

   for(var i =0,el;i<hash.length; i++ ){
        el=hash[i].split('=')
        parsed[el[0]] = el[1];
   }
   return parsed;
};

var obj= location.parseHash();
    obj.hash;  //fdg 
    obj.hfh;   //value2x
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on `&` and then on `=`:

```
pairs = location.hash.substr(1).split('&').map(function(pair) {
    var kv = pair.split('=', 2);
    return [decodeURIComponent(kv[0]), kv.length === 2 ? decodeURIComponent(kv[1]) : null];
})
```

Here `pairs` will be an array of arrays with the key at `0` and the value at `1`:

```
[["hfh","fdg"],["hash","value2x"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing extensive url manipulations, then you shoud check out [JQuery URL plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser).

To access the params in url hashes

```
    $.url('http://www.google.com/#hfh=fdg&hash=value2x').fparam('hash');
```

or if its current url

```
    $.url().fparam('hash');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This helps, I got that before also, Sorry that I din't specify earlier but I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If url has `?`: http://www.google.com/#?hash=value2x

The code can be:

```
const url = 'http://www.google.com/#?hash=value2x';
new URLSearchParams(
  (
    new URL(url)
  ).hash.slice(1).split('?')[1]
).get('hash');
```

Or if `url` has no `?`:

```
const url = 'http://www.google.com/#hash=value2x';
(new URLSearchParams((new URL(url)).hash.slice(1))).get('hash')
```