# Make auto adjustable script in PHP iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Hello i want to make something like this:

`<script>fid="canal1"; width=650; height=440;</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pirlotv.me/embed.js"></script>`

That script create an autoadjustable iframe

As you can see [here](http://www.pirlotves.com/player/canal1.php?width=650&height=440)

That `<iframe>` contains an script with a video stream

[image]

When you change the width or height property in the `URL` it also changes in the html document, how can I do something like that? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you will have to do something like this:

In the `URL` use get variables like so: `www.mywebsite.com/page.php?width=200&height=300`

Then use `echo $_GET['width'];` and `echo $_GET['height'];` to print where you need.

For example:

```
<script>fid="canal1"; width=<?php echo $_GET['width'];?>; height=<?php echo $_GET['height'];?>;</script>
```

I would also recomment using `isset()` function to see if the `$_GET` vars are actually set and if not assign some default value.. like this:

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '250'; //250 being the default value ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, you undestood, Is there a way to make it with HTML or Javascript?

Comment: You can get the Get variables using javascript like [this example](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/). You can read the hash using [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920697/how-to-get-hash-value-in-a-url-in-js)

Comment: But in PHP i cant use it :S http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/php/canal1.php?width=650&height=440, i cant quit that: ({"SCRIPTDATA":" it seems that it changes the code.

Comment: And i dont understand that example in javascript, it would be easier without using php

Comment: Without `PHP`: add the code underneath "The Code" from [this webpage](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/) to your site above the `<script>` you created, then do: `<script>fid="canal1"; width=getUrlVars()["width"]; height=getUrlVars()["height"];</script>`

Comment: But i mean to combine html and javascript without using php, its because a huge number of users will visit it and the php server is paid and the html free

Comment: **MY LAST COMMENT DOES NOT USE PHP AT ALL** :) hope you read it..

Comment: The example is this one: http://mywebpage.com/index.php?id=123&page=home
can it be  http://mywebpage.com/index.html?id=123&page=home ??

Comment: yes :). make sure you don't use <?php ?> anywhere in the page...