# Toggle Pop-up using JQuery and Hashtag based URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, url-routing

I've got 3 pop-ups on my page.  They function using JQuery and the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open_thanks').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tPop = $('.thanks_popup');
        tPop.toggle();
    });
    $('#open_reference').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rPop = $('.leave_reference_popup');
        rPop.toggle();
    });
    $('#facebook').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fPop = $('.facebook_popup');
        fPop.toggle();
    });


    $('.thanks_popup').append('<div class="close"><div class="inner"><button></button></div></div>');
    $('.leave_reference_popup').append('<div class="close"><div class="inner-2"><button></button></div></div>');
    $('.facebook_popup').append('<div class="close"><div class="inner-3"><button></button></div></div>');

    $('div.inner button').click(function() {
        var tPop = $('.thanks_popup');
        tPop.toggle();
    });
    $('div.inner-2 button').click(function() {
        var rPop = $('.leave_reference_popup');
        rPop.toggle();
    });
    $('div.inner-3 button').click(function() {
        var fPop = $('.facebook_popup');
        fPop.toggle();
    });

});
```

My html is quite simple:

```
<a href="#" id="open_thanks">Thanks Popup</a>

<a href="#" id="open_reference">Open Reference</a>

<a href="#" id="facebook">Open Facebook Popup</a>
```

I can't figure out how to use hashtag URL navigation to have a pop-up default as open though?  Basically, I want to be able to link to index.html#open_thanks and have that pop-up default as open/up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load, parse out any hash values in the url, and then do x.

[How to get #hash value in a URL in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920697/how-to-get-hash-value-in-a-url-in-js)

Comment: Not functioning for me.  A noob at JS.  I added the following to the JS code above:

function getHashValue(key) {
  return location.hash.match(new RegExp(key+'=([^&]*)'))[1];
}

// usage
var hash = getHashValue('hash');

function do_check()
{
    if(hash == tPop)
    {
        var tPop = $('.thanks_popup');
        tPop.toggle();
        }
}

Comment: More readable when you look at the bottom of the JS here: http://jsfiddle.net/XHUCG/

Comment: I edited your fiddle so that it might work. http://jsfiddle.net/XHUCG/6/ Try the code on your webpage though. I don't think jsfiddle can detect window.location.hash for some odd reason.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XHUCG/7/ Updated. Tested locally and it works, at least at http://localhost/index.html#hash=thanks

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks! Why does it need to be hash=thanks instead of just thanks?

Comment: It could be just "thanks". In that case, use location.hash instead of calling getHashValue(). The advantage to this function is that you can emulate parameters; e.g., #action=thank&name=Jackson, and then the popup would say "Thank you so much, Mr./Mrs. Jackson."