# Get values of all the same parameter from url in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an url have contain two parameters.

Ex: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=news&oq=news&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.299j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=bbc

```
Parameter 1: q=news

Parameter 2:q=bbc
```

I want to get all value have the same parameter, but I can only get value in first the parameter.

This is my code:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&#]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: please post your jquery code..

Comment: I don't think you can have two parameter values with same name, you can use `q1` and `q2`.

Comment: The second one comes from `location.hash`.

Comment: Of course you can have duplicate query string params.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(location).attr('href');` and parse through the parameters yourself

Answer (score 0):

what i have tried is only IDEA of how you can get all paremater.

```
 var a="https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=news&oq=news&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.299j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=bbc"
 var b= a.split("?")[1]
 b.split("&")
```

By this technique you will get all parameter.
You need to convert this code to your required code.

Answer (score 0):

The first `q` is in **querystring**, the second one is in **hash**. You should parse them in JavaScript:

## QueryString

```
// the method is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/3971911
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

## Hash

```
// the method is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11920807/3971911
function getHashValue(key) {
  return location.hash.match(new RegExp(key+'=([^&]*)'))[1];
}
```

Now you can use them like this:

```
alert(qs['q']); // news
alert(getHashValue('q')); // bbc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url,position) {
  url=position==1?url:url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('#'));
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&#]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
  results = regex.exec(url);
  return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

 var url='https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=news&oq=news&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.299j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=bbc';

alert(getParameterByName('q',url,1));
alert(getParameterByName('q',url,2));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/23/)

Answer (score 0):

Other than an exercise in coding, you're probably better off using existing code.

Something like:

- https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string

Pros:

- It has tests
- It's had more useful eyes cast over it (guessing here).
- The people that have likely contributed to it will probably have used it.
- If you find an issue with it, those people involved will have a keen interest in solving the problem as they're likely using it.

Cons:

- None! :D