# How to set dropdown list value with the value of a link by clicking that link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a value for dropdown list by clicking a link, i tried something like this, but it isn't working :

```
<html>
 <body>
    <select id="select">
       <option value="one">one</option>
       <option value="two">Two</option>
       <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select><br />

  <a class="link1" value="two" href="page.php?cc=two">Two</a><br /><br />
  <a class="link1" value="three" href="page.php?cc=three">Three</a>

  <script> 
       function setSelect () {

           var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName('link1');

             for (i = 0; i < elmnt.length; i++) {
                    elmnt[i].onclick = function () {
                    document.getElementById('select').value = elmnt[i].getAttribute("value");
                    window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
                    return false;

                    };                  
            }
       }


       setSelect ();

    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I also tried getting a value from the URL into the dropdown list by clicking the link, it didn't work, so i'm trying to set the drop downlist with the link value.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < elmnt.length; i++) {
  elmnt[i].onclick = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      document.getElementById('select').value = elmnt[i].getAttribute("value");
      window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
      return false;
    };
  })(i)
}`

Comment: Do you think you can help me achieve the same thing but with a value from the `href` ? as i have in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132470/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-dropdown-list-with-a-value-from-url-by-clicking-on-a-li)

Answer (score 0):

issue in your javascript code please add this

```
<script>
    function setSelect() {

        var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName('link1');

        for (i = 0; i < elmnt.length; i++) {
            elmnt[i].onclick = (function (i) {
                return function () {
                    document.getElementById('select').value = elmnt[i].getAttribute("value");
                    window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form', this.getAttribute("href"));
                    return false;
                };
            })(i)
        }
    }
    setSelect();

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You very much @kapil. Do you think you can help me achieve the same thing but with a value from the `href` ? as i have in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132470/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-dropdown-list-with-a-value-from-url-by-clicking-on-a-li)