# Get hash value from url

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I'm trying to get the hash value after a link was clicked. Any ideas?

e.g.

The Link

```
index.html#needThis
```

This is my result:

```
index.htmlneedThis
```

How can I remove the 'index.html' ?

```
$('#myselector').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') //get url
    console.log(hash);
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery. You don't need to 'remove' the `index.html`, you need to grab only the hash.

Comment: Why al all answers using `$(this).attr('href')`?! Use native JS where possible: `this.href` has the exact same value, withouth the need for another library or function calls.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**update**

Modern browsers (*not sure how back it goes*) can extract the `hash` directly from anchor elements (*so i added #5*)

---

Take your pick ..

1. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];`
2. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?#/,'');`
3. `var href = $(this).attr('href'), hash = href.substr(href.indexOf('#')+1);`
4. `var hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/#(.*$)/)[1];`
5. `var hash = this.hash.substr(1);`

---

**update**

Just revisited this and i believe that #2 can be improved to

```
$(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,'');
```

This way if no hash exists it will return empty instead of the whole url..

Comment: The second is the perfect solution! No Exception : var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?#/,''); thank you @Gaby

Comment: @gaby what is test in the 3. solution?

Comment: @TobiasOberrauch, great eyes... I have corrected it ... (*it was supposed to be a temporary reference to the `href` string*)

Comment: @Bellash just posted an improvement to it :)

Answer (score 16):

Just use `var hash = window.location.hash`.

It returns everything after #

Or if you've got a variable which contains an url:

```
$(this).attr('href').substring($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#'))
```

Comment: Thank you for that but it's not working in my case because I need the href of the a-element which is triggered and not from the current url. :)

Comment: in that case use a.substring(a.indexOf('#'))

Comment: `window.location.hash` doesn't actually *return everything after #*, but *everything **starting from** #*, so # character is included.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with window location hash.

```
$('#myselector').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var hash = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') //get url
    var hash2 = window.location.hash ;
    console.log(hash2);
})
```

Comment: Thank you but the same problem as above.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use:

```
window.location.hash
```

Works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#myselector').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href') //get url
    var arr = url.split('#');
    alert(arr[0]); //URL without hash #
    var hash = arr[1];
    console.log(hash);
})​
```