# How to change CSS display property using an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page in which there is an anchor tag: `<a href="tut.html#div2">jump to div2</a>`.

This anchor tag opens `tut.html`, which has a `div` with `id=div2`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div id="div1">
                --some content--
            </div>
            <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
                --some content--
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

By default, the contents of `div2` are hidden. How can I display or fade in its contents when a user clicks on a hyperlink in another page?

Comment: If you’re looking for a CSS-only solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget

Comment: @CBroe waw I did not know that even existed. Cool.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Perhaps starting by [examining the `hash`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344221/get-hash-value-from-url) when loading the page?

Comment: You might need to use some iFrames.

Comment: @Moojjoo What? Don't suggest `iframes`. If we can get rid of them the world would be a better place.

Comment: @CBroe Nice. Won't work with IE8 or lower, but that's a warning, not a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check the `hash` that is passed in and use that to display the appropriate block:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.querySelector(location.hash);
    if(element) element.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more how can i use really in my example above. I have no knowledge about 'hash'.

Comment: A hash is the part of a url that represents an element in this case. The code works as is. For more info, google `location.hash MDN`

Comment: Thank you sir. I was able to do what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

your href link should not link to the page, just to the anchor :

```
<a class="myButton" href="#div2">link</a>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
           <div id="div1">
              --some content--
           </div>
           <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
              --some content--
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, you should have a function in the bottom of your document which would handle your click like this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a.myButton').on('click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $('div2').fadeIn('slow');
          return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But this will work only if i have the anchor tag in the same page.In this case,anchor tag lies on different page.

Comment: Ok then if your link is on a different page, then keep your href like you said:
    <a href="tut.html#div2">jump to div2</a>
and on the page tut.html add this script :

    $(function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if(hash == '#div2') $(hash).fadeIn('slow');
    });

Answer (score 1):

If the link goes to a new page:

```
<a href="tut.html#div2">link</a>
```

On the bottom of the new page 'tut.html' :

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash == '#div2') $(hash).fadeIn('slow');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: presuming you use jQuery library.