# After button clicked, change to different page and show hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some "Learn More" links on my Home page, all of which correspond to different sections of content that is on the More Info page. These different sections of content are all hidden using display: none.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to make it so that when I click a particular "Learn More" link, the user will be sent to the More Info page, and the section of content corresponding to the Learn More link they clicked will be shown.

I can't think of a way to achieve this, but I'm hoping it will be possible, perhaps using JavaScript.

EDIT:
The code I currently have is nothing special. Four `<a>` links on the Home page, then on the More Info page, four divs that are all initially hidden using `display: none`.

Comment: Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22read+more%22+javascript

Comment: I didn't share any code as I felt it would be better to adapt my code to a potential solution for this problem, rather than try to solve the problem given my current code. I'll add in something about it now though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being fairly simple, I did what is described in the top answer of this question: [Getting URL hash location, and using it in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="javascript:showContent('id_here');">Learn more</a>

 <script>
    function showContent(id) {
        $("#"+id).show();
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I know how to show content, but my issue is having the link take the user to a different page, then showing a particular, corresponding section of content that will be set to `display: none` on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible.You can take the information on a div,and then you click "Learn more",show the div.
In this way,you even needn't a hyperlink,just a click event,like the code upstairs.Of course,this div was hidden before.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this would be to add a hash to that link with the id of the section you want to show, like this: `<a href="/moreinfo#section-id">Learn More</a>`. Then just check for it in `window.location.hash` on the /moreinfo page and show the div.

Comment: Hmm, could you please elaborate on how I would use `window.location.hash` to show the corresponding div?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way: `try to use named anchors`.

## first:

```
<a href="your-page-url-here#section-3">Learn More</a>
```

when use clicks this link user will navigate to particular page with different sections.

## second:

on this page suppose you want to show the 3rd section:

```
 .....
 <a name='section-3'></a>
 <h1>Your section-3</h1>
```

In your case `divs are hidden` then use js or jQuery for this:

As you will get a hash in the location url then use  `.substr()' and`.indexOf()` javascript methods.

try to `put this script` on those page `where you are having your hidden divs`

```
$(function(){
   var url = window.location.href;
   var obj = url.substr(url.indexOf('#'));
   $(obj).show();
});
```

Comment: How would I go about showing the corresponding div, since they are all set to `display: none`?

Comment: then you can find the hash in the location and use that as id or class then show with js or jquery.