# jquery handling of anchor links for multiple pages

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the fancy FAQ code found here (the "elegant" version at the bottom to be precise);
http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-sliders

What I would like to do is to create anchors for each one of my FAQ questions and provide links to the appropriate question in email using these anchors.  In addition, I would like the show/hide jquery code to recognize when an incoming request has targeted the specific question and slidetoggle() to show the matching answer.

I am stuck trying to figure out how the jquery code for the FAQ page can parse the href and associated anchor value that was used to load the page.  Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Base HTML example;

```
<h3>This is question 1?</h3>
<div>
    <p>This is the answer to question #1.  Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
</div>
<h3>This is question 2?</h3>
<div>
    <p>This is the answer to question #2.  Pellentesque habitant morbi....</p>
</div>
<!-- more... -->
```

And the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#faqs h3').each(function() {
        var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
        tis.click(function() {
            state = !state;
            answer.slideToggle(state);
            tis.toggleClass('active',state);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try re-phrasing your question, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want.

Comment: I would like to provide a link via email to my FAQ page something like this; http:\\mysite\FAQ.html#QUESTION1
On my FAQ page, I would like the page to load to the anchor for QUESTION1 and I would like the jquery code that handles the slidetoggle to correctly make visible the answer for question1.  Currently the slidetoggle works only for clicks on the questions with the FAQ page loaded.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location.hash` property contains the hash value. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location). Once you have this value, it should be quite simple to `slideToggle()` the corresponding FAQ.

Comment: Ah ok!  I think this is all I needed to point me in the right direction.  I will update after I get it working.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I cannot seem to get the hash value.  If I run this; `if (window.location.hash){
   console.log ("FOUND HASH");
  }else{ 
    console.log ("HASH NOT FOUND");
  }`

I always get the else clause.  However if I look at the DOM value directly I can clearly see the hash in the URL.  I am corn-fused.

Comment: This answer resolved my original question.  Now I am having trouble implementing it and asked a follow-up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494058/jquery-not-returning-url-hash).