# jquery send to new web page + pass variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

On the "about" page of my website, the click of the "Next" button will go through a few slides. 
This is done using a variable called "count", and jquery:

```
$("#NextBtn").click(function() {
  count = count + 1
});
```

And

```
$("#NextBtn").click(function(){

/*on count=0, the background image is shown*/

if (count==1) {
  $('#slides').slideToggle();
};


if (count==2) {
  $("#slide_1").hide()
$("#slide_2").show()

};

if (count==3) {
  $("#slide_2").hide()
$("#slide_3").show()

};
```

On the click of a link on my home page (./*home.html), i would like to send the user to this "about" page, with slide number 2 displayed.

```
<a href="./*about.html">Click here</a>
```

How can I do this? Can i pass the redirection a value of "count"? Can i tell jquery that if the user is coming from the home page, display slide 2?

I'm at loss as to what to do... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you can simply initialize count to '2' before all this function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying slides while staying on the page, you can simply keep track of the variable. If you are not, then these are a few ways:

- Pass `GET` data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/901144#901144). Changes url (good for sending links, bad for short urls), also visible on server
- Pass `POST` data. Not really an option if you can't change the server (and not a very good one otherwise), but doesn't change url.
- Set a cookie. might give weird behaviour if there are multiple tabs/windows.
- Add a `#` location. I think this is most appropriate, if you're not already using # for something else. Won't interfere with forms GET data, but lets users send url's with the correct slide to friends. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery).

TL;DR: Add the slide number to the redirect url with a `#` before it, then use `window.location.hash` to retrieve it on the next page.

EDIT: here's working example code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var def = '#slide1';

            function slide_jump(goal)
            {
                if (goal[0] == '#')
                {
                    goal = goal.substring(1)
                }
                $('[name^="slide"]').hide();
                if (goal)
                {
                    $('[name=' + goal + ']').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.replace(def);
                    $('[name=#' + goal + ']').show();
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                slide_jump(document.location.hash);
                $('#nav a').each(function(k, elem)
                {
                    $(elem).click(function (elem, event)
                    {
                        slide_jump($(elem).attr('href'));

                    }.bind(null, elem));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="#slide1">First</a>
            <a href="#slide2">Second</a>
        </div>
        <div name="slide1">
            Hello and welcome on slide 1!
        </div>
        <div name="slide2">
            So we are on slide 2, then?
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this the right way to do it? Doesn't work for me... if (count==2) {   window.location.hash = 'this_slide'; $("#slide_1").hide()
$("#slide_2").show()}

Comment: and then <a href="./*about.html#this_slide">Click here</a> ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your reply; I added an example that works!

Answer (score 0):

> Can i pass the redirection a value of "count"?

Sure, it just takes a little code.  You can append a query string value with the data you want to pass along to the next page.  But since that value is dynamic, you'll need to handle the actual clicking of the link in JavaScript.  So the link itself might be something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="aboutLink">Click here</a>
```

And in JavaScript you'd do something like this:

```
$('#aboutLink').click(function () {
    window.location = 'about.html?count=' + count;
});
```

Of course, this assumes that the `count` value is in scope at that time.  If it's not, you'd have to find a way to make it available, such as moving it to a higher scope or perhaps writing another function that determines the current count and returns it.

Of course, how you subsequently *use* that value on the next page is another story entirely.  If everything is client-side code (which is somewhat implied by the `.html` extension, I think) then you'd be looking to [use query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the variable count:

```
<a href="./*about.html?count=2">Click here</a>
```

You can grab the number passed through to count via this: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Then, have your jQuery advance to the appropriate slide.