# Change bootstrap tabs when coming from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with topics set in a bootstrap tabbed panel. 
I want to have links to the topics from another page.
Is it possible when I click to a button when I go to the tabbed page the active tab to change automatically?
i.e. on page2.html to click a link and go to tab2 or tab3 on page1.html

```
<!-- tabs -->
<div id="helptabs">
<!-- tab pills -->
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="container" id="fpills">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="device-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topic 1</a></li><li
                    role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="faq-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topic 2</a></li><li
                    role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="help-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topic 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- tab pills END -->

<!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Topic 1 comes here</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Topic 2 comes here</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Topic 3 comes here</div>
    </div>
<!-- tab panes END -->
</div>
<!-- tabs -->
```

And on the other page it should be

```
<a href="[link to page1]">Topic1</a>
<a href="[link to page1 tab2]">Topic2</a>
<a href="[link to page1 tab3]">Topic3</a>
```

Comment: do you want to change/select a specific tab on page load ?

Comment: Code sample of what you have tried so far would be helpful..

Comment: @user3273700 yes I want to change no a specific tab when I click the link

Comment: @Nivedit I added the code, it is standard bootstrap tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is probably here, take a look.

[Bootstrap tabs opening tabs on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163188/bootstrap-tabs-opening-tabs-on-another-page)

Comment: Please do explain you answer too.

Comment: Thank you @Saa_keetin, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: ur welcome, if you still need explanation let me know :)