# Redirect to a Anchor of a page an action click event on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an UL tag with several LI's every LI has his own UL.
On desktop device, the second UL displays Block by hovering the first level LI.
But on the Mobile device I want to make it on click.

In the header, I have a Contact Us button, that triggers a click event on that LI so the Contact Us text appears, this works fine only if this happens on the page with the contact field, but if I'm on a another page I don't know how to target that page and make a click action on it.

I think its something like, detecting the link in the URL, if after  has a hash tag take that tag find it in page, if you find it make a Click event on it.

But I don't really know how to write the code for it.

The HTML structure looks something like this :

```
<div id="ClickForContact">Contact Us</div>



<ul>
  <li>
     <a>Something else</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="contact">Contact</a>
    <ul class="subMenu" >
        <li>
            <p>Some text here and there.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QkB9T/1/

So any help here?

Comment: you can grab the URL with a `GET` method. If you can use PHP

Comment: I know, but I want a clean solution and mostly JQuery,Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery

Comment: Thanks very much for the duplicate post, it helped me find an answer, I will post below my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page the contact button is I made this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.hash;
    var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')); // '#foo'
    if(hash == '#contactUs'){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#contactUs').click();
            window.clearTimeout();
        },500);

    }
});
</script>
```

and in the header I put :

```
<a href="<? echo base_url . '#contactUs'; ?>">Contact</a>
```

Inspiration came from this post :
[Getting URL hash location, and using it in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QkB9T/2/

HTML

```
<a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Something else</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="contact">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subMenu" >
            <li>
                <p>Some text here and there.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    .subMenu{
    display:none;
}

ul li:hover .subMenu,
ul li a:target + .subMenu{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Just like that, but want this action even from a another page, something like : what you made is the homepage, and I'm on the Team page and the Button that you made clickable is in the header so when I click it I want to get redirected to the Homepage + that action you made in JsFiddle

Comment: Then the link would be: <a href="homepage.html#contact">Contact us</a>