# on click, go to another page and open a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an FAQ page with all questions in a list. The list only shows the questions. The answers are hidden and slide down when you click on a question.

On other pages there are links to these questions. I need them to open the FAQ page and directly show the answer as well.

I suppose this has something to do with location/targeting, but don't really know how to solve it.

This is the HTML on the FAQ page

```
<ul> 
   <li class="#faq1">
      <h1 class="question">
         This is were the question goes.
      </h1>

      <div class="answer">
          This is were the answer goes, only showing when clicking the question or a link on another page linked to this question.
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answer").hide();

  $(".question").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

On some other pages I use normal links. When clicking the link, it obviously opens the FAQ page, but it does not toggle the answer.

```
<a href="faq">This is were the question goes</a>
```

What can I do to trigger the slideToggle from another page?

Comment: Pass a hashtag in the URL, [grab it with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery), and use it to determine which section to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the answer to display in the hash of the URL.

1. Change the HTML to include a unique id for each answer tag.

```
<ul> 
   <li class="#faq1">
      <h1 class="question">
         This is were the question goes.
      </h1>

      <div class="answer" id="answer1">
          This is were the answer goes, only showing when clicking the question or a link on another page linked to this question.
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

2. Change the Javascript so that it picks up any hash and shows that answer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answer").hide();

  // show the target answer
  if (window.location.hash)
    $(location.hash).slideToggle(500);

  $(".question").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

3. Change the href of the source link on the other page to include the id of the answer you want to display as the hash.

`<a href="faq#answer1">This is were the question goes</a>`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

If you are set to use client side processing for this here's a solution

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

To use just call

```
var flag = GetURLParameter('goto');
```

So, if you go to the url  http://example.com/?goto=answer flag will contain "answer" and you will know were to scroll.